# Mongoose and angular filter results only with photo

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, mongoose

I developed a filter checkbox to pass the parameter to "filter results only with photo".

If I put the code below directly on the server works, but via angular goes wrong.

Is there another way to do this?

```
$scope.query = {
    picture: { $exists: true }
};
```

My server router:

```
app.get('/api/users', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res) {

    console.log(req.query);

    User.find(req.query, function(err, users) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        }
        res.json(users);
    })
    .sort({ rating: -1 });
});
```

And my controller checkbox:

```
<md-checkbox class="md-primary" ng-model="query.picture" ng-change="loadusers()">filter results only with photo</md-checkbox>
```

My function retrieve server

```
$scope.loadusers = function(){

        $ionicLoading.show({
            template: 'Carregando...'
        });

        diaristajaAPI.all('users').getList($scope.query)

        .then(function(users){
            $ionicLoading.hide();
            $scope.listusers = users;
        })

        .catch(function(error) {
            $ionicLoading.hide();
            if (error.error) {
                // Popup error - invalid redirect_uri, pressed cancel button, etc.
                $mdToast.showSimple(error.error);
            } else if (error.data) {
                // HTTP response error from server
                $mdToast.showSimple(error.data.message, error.status);
            } else {
                $mdToast.showSimple(error);
            }
        });

    };
```

Comment: We need the code showing how you communicate from angular to your server

Comment: OK, gone! my function

Answer (score 1):

Use a boolean for the checkbox.

```
$scope.query = {picture: true};
```

Then on the server it's simple to just do

```
req.query.picture = {$exists: !!req.query.picture};
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! It worked in parts, implemented o'que you went, now only without photo users are listed. And if I take them !!It gives me an error in angle.

Comment: I need the checkbox, make a toggle between users with photo and all photo and no.

Comment: i try this if(req.query.picture) req.query.picture = { $exists: true, $ne: [] };